Cron Job in Namecheap shared hosting and Laravel
I am a newbie in Laravel. I am trying to run a Cron job in Laravel on Namecheap shared hosting.
When I run the script through browser it works perfectly.
URL - https://mydomain.app/api/block-numbers-company

I am trying to set up a CRON taks in cPanel and I have this command setup
*/5 *   *   *   *   /usr/bin/php -q /home/userhome/mydomain.app/api/block-numbers-company

This doesn't gets executed.
Can someone guide me please?

Why do you want to setup a CRON in cPanel where within laravel application you can set CRON? Which version of laravel you are using??

/usr/bin/php -q /home/userhome/mydomain.app/api/block-numbers-company. I'm pretty sure this doesn't do what you think it does
